# How long until tamed wolves stop attacking in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a new dog and I accidentally hit an iron  golem. That iron golem is player made, so it will not attack me, but then my dog tried to attack him. Before anything happens, **I asked my dog to sit.** How long until I can *make the dog stand* without attacking the iron golem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wolf#Behavior_and_appearance) (emphasis mine):

> Angry wolves have a constant growling and fearsome appearance. Wild wolves become hostile when they are either attacked by a player or mob, or when they see a mob they want to eat. Their tail is held out straight, their eyes become blood red, their mouth is raised in a slight snarl, and they have angry eyebrows. Angry wolves are hostile only to mobs that attack them, or the mobs which they are hunting. They can see attackers even if they are under the invisibility effect, ***but they cannot track the attacker down, if they get out of their render distance, or the attacker was able to unload the chunk where the wolves were***. Angry wolves cannot be leashed, but a wild wolf may become angry while it is still leashed without dropping the lead.

Since, in your situation, the target is a Golem, the best way to manage this would be to travel away from the golem quickly, and [allow your wolf to teleport with you](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wolf#Teleportation) (emphasis mine):

> ***Teleporting resets the focus of a tamed wolf, so if a wolf is attacking a mob and teleports beside a player, it resumes following the player, as its tracking has been reset***.

Additionally, you have to allow the wolf to teleport with you. It will *not* teleport:

- If the wolf has been ordered to sit.
- If the wolf is in a minecart or a boat.
- If the wolf has been attached to a fence post with a lead.
- If the wolf is in an unloaded chunk.
- If the owner is not directly touching the ground (e.g. using elytra, swimming, flying, in a boat).

Comment: The Wolf in the situation was not an angry wolf, it was tamed and responding to its owner

Comment: @RayWu this answer covers that; a Tamed Wolf can only teleport to its owner. A Wild Wolf cannot. Angry Wolves and Tamed Angry Wolves behave in the same way, regardless.

Comment: You don't mention teleporting in your answer,

Comment: The entire section after my first quote is all about teleportation.

Comment: Your entire answer is one quote? Angry wolves have a constant growling and fearsome appearance. Wild wolves become hostile when they are either attacked by a player or mob, or w like that quote is your entire answer?

Comment: @RayWu Ben's answer is considerably more than one quote ([screenshot](https://carcer.co.uk/random/arqanswer.png)). Can you screenshot what you're seeing?

Comment: @Carcer nvm I saw it now, I was browsing on mobile